# Playing different sounds simultaneously while clicking buttons

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

How should I proceed
    As you can see here, three sounds play at the same time
    https://yadi.sk/i/eUtfS0to-0ZreQ

Hello everyone, When I click the button, the sound does not turn off and two or three sounds start playing at the same time.
        I'm sorry I did this on the printer translation site.

```
     public void music1(View view) {
            contra=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.contraolu);
           contra.start();

        }

        public void music2(View view) {
            tankurt=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.tankurtmaanascenekemiklerim);
            tankurt.start();

        }

        public void music3(View view) {
            norm=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.normenderciktikyineyollara);
            norm.start();

        }




    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:onClick="music2"
            android:text="Tankur Manas-Çene Kemiklerimi Kırdım"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
            android:onClick="music3"
            android:text="Norm Ender- Çıktık Yine Yollara"

            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
            android:onClick="music1"
            android:text="Contra-Ölü"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Comment: When you click each button, you have to stop the media player and the create new sound.

Comment: You have to stop the active player instance, if you want to play only one sound at a time.

Comment: I'm new, do you have a chance to tell me more?

Answer (score 1):

Use a single MediaPlayer, stop it before starting another new sound.

```
 MediaPlayer mp;
public void music1(View view) {
            stopPlayingSound();
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.contraolu);
            mp.start();

        }
        public void music2(View view) {
            stopPlayingSound();
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.tankurtmaanascenekemiklerim);
            mp.start();

        }

        public void music3(View view) {
            stopPlayingSound();
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.normenderciktikyineyollara);
            mp.start();

        }

       void stopPlayingSound() {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the player before playing you next music. I suggest you create a public field named `mediaPlayer` and then you can stop it in each method and play new music with it.

Comment: I'm new, do you have a chance to tell me more?

        }